# Compare pairs of columns from different Spark dataframes in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 different dataframes:

| value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 111 |
| bbb | 222 |
| ccc | 333 |

and

| value_3 | value_4 |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 222 |
| aaa | 111 |
| bbb | 111 |

What I want to achieve is to filter the first dataframe such as the pair of columns (value_1, value_2) has values ​​equal to a pair from the second dataframe (value_3, value_4).

So in this case, the first dataframe filtered by this condition should contain only:

| value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 111 |

Is there any way I can filter by pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join dataframes.

```scala
df1
  .join(df2, col("value_1") === col("value_3") && col("value_2") === col("value_4"))
  .select("value_1", "value_2")
```

In general, if you want to do something with two dataframes, joining them should be the first method you should think about.